# How does a Razor Layout get the name of the View using it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My Layout displays a menu using Html.RenderAction. The Action needs the Controller name and View name passed to it so it can work out what menu options to display depending on the user's profile and the page they are on. 
I can obtain the Controller name using ViewContext.Controller.ToString() but can't find an equivalent for the View that is using the Layout. It must be there somewhere, but I've run out of guesses.
I know I could put it in the ViewBag for each View, but that depends on remembering to do it every time, which I am now too old and tired to depend on.

Comment: See if this other question will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311463/how-to-get-the-current-view-name-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 3):

Can you tie it to the action instead of the view being rendered?  You can get the action from the RouteData on the ViewContext.

```
var action = ViewContext.RouteData["action"] as string;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, @tvanfosson - it will certainly work for current purposes, and I will add it as a parameter to my MenuManager. But I expect later to have some actions that render different views depending on the circumstances, so I would be grateful if anyone can tell me how to get the View name.

Comment: also `@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")`