# How to get the current view name in asp.net MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I get the current view name regarding to current URL, in asp.net MVC 3 using Razor engine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398189/getting-current-controller-action-from-within-partial-view

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No idea why you would need to get the current view name but you could use the `VirtualPath` property inside a view. Normally it's more useful to know the current action or controller. But anyway, here's how to get the current view name:

```
@VirtualPath
```

and if you wanted to get only the filename:

```
@Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(VirtualPath))
```

and without the extension:

```
@Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Server.MapPath(VirtualPath))
```

Comment: +1 This works nice - it should be the accepted answer. By the way, I tried it without mapping the path and it works just as well. In general `Path` should be ok with relative paths. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: One very useful thing the @VirtualPath can be used for - a key to lookup the localizations for that view from a data source.

Comment: perhaps it isn't the best way to do it but I like to create a .js and .css per view.  I then like to include them both in the view, for which having the name of the view is most useful.  so thanks for the reply

Comment: You can add a body class depending on the view with the same action/controller, very useful in some cases.

Comment: Any idea how I can get the actual view file name? VirtualPath will show the name of the layout file and not the actual view using the layout if you show this in the layout. As for those asking - its very nice during development to show both controller class, action and view file so you know how to reach a certain view/controller quickly.

Comment: How can I access this from the view engine?   I can embed it on a cshtml page as @VirtualPath, but as soon as control moves into a Html.Partial method... there seems to be no way for it to figure out what cshtml file made the call.  I'd really like access to this value from within my RazorViewEngine's FindView methods for more intelligent locating of views.

Answer (score 8):

I've also tested this code, and I could do something with it.
But, I'm not sure if is this a good solution or not.

For example, I need to detect the Contacts view located in Home directory. So I wrote:

```
if (@Request.RawUrl == "/Home/Contacts")
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get it from RequestContext.RouteData
specifically, its Values collection contains "controller" and "action" keys
i.e.
RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]

Comment: No, this will get the action name. The action name does not necessarily correlate strictly to a specific view name.

Comment: You will find that this is the case often enough to be useful.

Comment: You might need to qualify it with HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Core's equivalent:

```
@ViewContext.ExecutingFilePath
```

Output is like this:

```
/Views/Shared/String.cshtml
```

> The rendering of a view may involve one or more files (e.g. _ViewStart, Layouts etc).
>   This property contains the path of the file currently being rendered.
>
> [ViewContext.ExecutingFilePath Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.viewcontext.executingfilepath?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Comment: I put it in _ViewStart , it always returns "Views/_ViewStart.cshtml"