# Getting current controller & action from within partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using the following to get the current controller and action in asp.net MVC3:

```
var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
```

This works perfectly. However, if I call this from within a partial view that is called from my layout, "Layout" is returned as the current controller. This is of course correct behaviour, but is there any way to access the parent controller's name?

***Edit for further clarification:***

I am calling my menu controller and partial view from within `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@Html.Action("Menu", "Layout")
```

Then from within that Menu partial view, I am calling code which returns the current action and controller.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you show how are you calling this partial?

Comment: @darin-dimitrov I've updated my post with some further information. Does this help at all?

Comment: yes it helps, you even get an answer :-)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After your updated question and showing your code it is much more clear: you are not including a partial view. You are calling a child action. There's a huge difference between `Html.Partial` and `Html.Action`. So if you want to get the parent context inside this child action you could do this:

```
public ActionResult Menu()
{
    var rd = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData;
    var currentAction = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
    var currentController = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
    ...
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Spot on. Thank you Darin - switching from Forms to MVC is a rather large jump but people like you are making the transition that little bit easier!

Answer (score 42):

I stumbled on this page looking for a way to access the parent controllers name after a call using Partial

```
@Html.Partial("Paging")
```

This can be done in the partial view as

```
@{
    var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    var action = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
}
```