# identify which action method to call when same view is requested from different view in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, routes, action

I am working on a MVC 5 project and I have a case where I am calling the same action/view from different views and I want to return to the same view from which the request is coming. Ex. Say I have three view A, B, C and A and C both call B at different times. Now I want to return to A or C respectively after the B action is complete. I have to use this B view from multiple actions/views in such a way that when B action is complete it redirect to the respective view which called B initially. I am looking for a generic solution. What would be the best way to do it. it would be very helpful if some example can be given by you helpful guys :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find the answer from another post in SO itself. I am posting it here in case anybody comes across this question.

To get the **action** which called the View, use this

```
ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
```

To get the **controller** which called the View, use this

```
ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
```

The link to the source is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398189/getting-current-controller-action-from-within-partial-view)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
public ActionResult B()
{
    //do something
    return Redirect(Request.Referrer);
}
```

alternatively, try this:

```
public ActionResult A()//Or C
{
    return RedirectToAction("B",
        new { r = Request.Url.ToString() });
}
```

then:

```
public ActionResult B()
{
    return Redirect(Request.QueryString["r"]);
}
```

These are generic solutions in **Controller** to meet your purpose.
If you want to redirect from a button in the **View**, use this:

```
<a href="@Request.UrlReferrer">B</a>
```

Comment: actually I want to know from the View, which action called the view. Will this help ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this

```
public ActionResult Action()
  {
    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
  }
```