# MVC 3 How to tell what view a controller action is being called from-

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, controller

Is there a way to tell what view a controller action is being called from?
For example, I would like to use "ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.PhysicalPath" but it returns the path in which the controller action itself is located:

```
    public ActionResult HandleCreateCustomer()
    {
        // Set up the customer
        //..code here to setup the customer

        //Check to see of the calling view is the BillingShipping view
        if(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.PhysicalPath.Equals("~/Order/BillingShipping"))
        {
            //
            return RedirectToAction("OrderReview", "Order", new { id = customerId });
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { id = customerId });
        }
    }
```

Comment: [does this answer help ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6311523/1551730)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed number of locations that it could possibly be called from, you could create an enum where each of the values would correspond to a place where it could have been called from. You'd then just need to pass this enum value into HandleCreateCustomer, and do your condition statement(s) based on that.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I am using something of the sort:

In the View I am populating a TempData variable using:

```
@{TempData["ViewPath"] = @Html.ViewVirtualPath()}
```

The HtmlHelper method ViewVirtualPath() is found in the System.Web.Mvc.Html namespace (as usual) and is as follows and returns a string representing the View's virtual path:

```
public static string ViewVirtualPath(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {            
        try{
            return ((System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase)(htmlHelper.ViewDataContainer)).VirtualPath;
        }catch(Exception){
            return "";
        }
    }
```

I will then obviously read the TempData variable in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way.
In the controller you want to know what page it was called from.
I added the following in my controller

```
ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;
```

Then in the View I have a 'Back' button

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button().Name("ReturnButton")
            .Content("Back to List").Events(e => e.Click("onReturn"))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "k-button" })
        )
```

Then the javascript for the onReturn handler

```
function onReturn(e) {
    var url = '@(ViewBag.ReturnUrl)';
    window.location.href = url;
}
```