# Razor - How do I output the current cshtml filename

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

For debugging purposes, I would like to output an HTML comment indicating the filename of the current cshtml file at the beginning and end of every cshtml file.

For example, I'd like so that when I view the source of the generated webpage, I would see something like this:

```
<!-- BEGIN _Layout.cshtml -->
... some headings and such ...
<!-- BEGIN About.cshtml -->
... generated content from the About.cshtml ...
<!-- END About.cshtml -->
... some footers and such ...
<!-- END _Layout.cshtml -->
```

I'm fairly new to this platform, so I'm not even sure what the right terminology is for this, let alone where in the API to look.  I'm hoping that at the very least I can edit all of my cshtml files and reference some object at runtime that contains the filename as a property, in a syntax similar to:

```
<!-- BEGIN @Object.OptionalProperty.OptionalSubProperty.Filename -->
```

Or, alternatively, a way to modify the rendering engine so that it automatically does this at the beginning and end of every rendered file.

Thank you so much for your time and responses.

Comment: [This answer may guide you in the direction you want](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6311523/254973).

Comment: @VirtualPath is exactly what I needed.  If only I knew the terminology better, I might have found that.  Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!