# Enable/disable a form control in Razor editor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an editor template where one of the form controls is disabled:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyField, new {@class = "form-control", disabled="disabled"})
```

The editor template is used in multiple views, and one view requires the textbox to be enabled, whereas in other views it needs to be disabled.

Is it possible to parameterize the template so that the control can be enabled/disabled depending on the view?

Comment: Add a `DisableForm` property to your view model?

Comment: @stuartd would it not be better to create two view models in that case?

Comment: Which ever you prefer, depending on your circumstances. You [can get the view name form within the view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311463/how-to-get-the-current-view-name-in-asp-net-mvc-3) though.

Comment: The `EditorFor()` method has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor``2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}},System.Object%29) for `additionalViewData` so you could pass a value to the template and use it to conditionally render the attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke Assume OP using MVC 5.1 or above, the `EditorFor` overload usage is possible. However on MVC 4 and below, a custom HTML helper returning `TextBoxFor` should be made, since `EditorFor` doesn't support `additionalViewData` attribute in previous versions.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, All versions of MVC support adding `additionalViewData` when using the `EditorFor()` method - your confused with adding `htmlAttributes` (and OP has a custom `EditorTemplate` containing `@Html.TextBoxFor()` etc - the `EditorFor()` in this case is for rendering that template, not a single form control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this based on the suggestion in the comments to use the `EditorForModel` overload that takes additional view data.

In the EditorTemplate:

```
@((bool)ViewData["MyFieldEnabled"] ?
    Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyField, new { @class = "form-control" }) :
    Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyField, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" }))
```

In the view:

```
@Html.EditorForModel(new { MyFieldEnabled = false })
```